# Split an XML file into multiples

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

This may have been asked before but I have an XML file that I need to split into individual ones.

The file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<invoices>
    <invoice>
        <data>

        </data>
    </invoice>
    <invoice>
        <data>

        </data>
    </invoice>
</invoices>
```

And I have my code to split this as:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <tosplit>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="//invoice" group-by="ceiling(position() div 1)">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="copy">
                    <xsl:with-param name="currentgroup" select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </tosplit>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="copy">
        <xsl:param name="currentgroup"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="copy">
                <xsl:with-param name="currentgroup" select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="invoices" mode="copy">
        <xsl:param name="currentgroup"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="copy"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$currentgroup" mode="copy"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This, however, does not do the trick. I want each file to look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tosplit>
   <invoices>
      <invoice>
         <data>

         </data>
      </invoice>
   </invoices>
</tosplit>
```

Any help  will be appreciated.

Comment: Learn about [`xsl:result-document`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#creating-result-trees).

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to an XSLT 3.0 processor like Saxon 9 PE or EE in oXygen or Altova's Raptor in XMLSpy 2017 then all you need is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip" streamable="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="invoice">
        <xsl:result-document href="invoice-split{position()}.xml">
            <xsl:copy-of select="snapshot(.)/root()"/>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to create one result document for each `invoice` element.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first see why your code doesn't work

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <tosplit>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="//invoice" group-by="ceiling(position() div 1)">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="copy">
                    <xsl:with-param name="currentgroup" select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </tosplit>
    </xsl:template>
```

I really don't know what you had in mind with that group-by attribute. If X is an integer (as position() is) then `ceiling(X div 1)` is going to return X unchanged. So it's the same as group-by="position()", and since the position of each item is different, each item will go in a separate group. Which means that your code is a convoluted way of doing:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <tosplit>
        <xsl:for-each select="//invoice" >
             <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="copy">
                 <xsl:with-param name="currentgroup" select="."/>
             </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
   </tosplit>
</xsl:template>
```

which in turn doesn't achieve anything that couldn't be done more naturally as

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <tosplit>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//invoice" mode="copy"/>
   </tosplit>
</xsl:template>
```

Basically, you're not doing any grouping, and from your problem statement you don't need to do any grouping, so it's hard to see what this code is all about.

At the same time, you say you want to produce one file per invoice but your code is making no attempt to produce multiple output files.